# Starting Lync conversation from C# WPF desktop app regardless of Lync client version installed

Tags: wpf, lync, skype-for-business, ucma, ucwa

I'm new to Lync integration and development.

I am trying to write a feature to allow an existing desktop WPF line of business application to launch a Lync conversation with another user on the local intranet where the app is running.

The difficulty I face is that the application will not know up front what version of Lync client is installed on the user's PC. The app is deployed in various organizations and therefore can't make assumptions about client or server side versions.

At this stage the app is going to try launch whichever version of the Lync executable it can find on the PC, with a shortcut SIP, as shown here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398376(v=ocs.14).aspx

"You can use command-line parameters to quick-start Microsoft Lync"

I am also considering the UCMA (server side) API, although I'm worried that again I will have to worry about what server version is running.

Is there a better "version agnostic" way of doing this?

It seems that each version of the client SDK is incompatible with previous versions. This will mean I need to first detect what version of Lync is installed; and then use the appropriate SDK. This will also mean distributing multiple copies of the Lync SDK; and will also likely mean needing to create a new version of the application when successive versions of Lync are released.

I did note that there might be a server-side API (UCMA) that I could use across the different versions of Lync/OCS/Skype for Business, although there are mentions that this API is more "advanced" and is "to be avoided".

Some reading I've done:

[what are difference between "Lync Server 2010 SDK" / "UCMA 3.0 SDK" / and UCC API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076536/what-are-difference-between-lync-server-2010-sdk-ucma-3-0-sdk-and-ucc-ap)

http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2014/07/lync-development-picking-the-right-api/

[Which Lync SDK? Send IMs from managed code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300082/which-lync-sdk-send-ims-from-managed-code)

Can anyone share any thoughts about this problem, have I missed something?

Ideally I'd like some kind of layer of abstraction where I could call a method to start a conversation, and not worry about what client is installed on the PC or what version is installed on the server. I realize this might be an unrealistic expectation!

I have tried searching through SO on the Lync tag; if this is a repeat question, sorry!

Comment: For now I decided to target Lync 2010 client SDK, but would still appreciate any input

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to connect a user of the LOB application with a support or outside user.  A general suggestion would be to consider UCMA as it would be available across Lync 2010, 2013, etc and you could consider using it as a middleman between LOB-user and support-user, but this would require server-side installation of the UCMA application.

Comment: Thanks @ShelbyZ - it is between users within a group of organisations that are arranged in an Active Directory forest - multiple domains and multiple versions of Lync installed at different locations

Comment: I suppose you could look at it a few ways.  If there is federation between all users/domains/etc then you could find one server and deploy the UCMA app as it will act like a Lync/Skype for Business user and be able to talk with anyone involved in the federation (requires only 1 deployment).  If there is no or limited federation between users/domains/etc then you are at the mercy of deploying N-times (where N is the minimum number required to reach all users).

Comment: In the no/limited federation scenario, would it still be possible to propogate conversations from user to user, across the domains, given multiple UCMA server side deployments?

Comment: Basically in the limited/no federation scenario user1 talks to ucmaBot which creates a conference and invites user2.  It is not ideal to start thinking about the number of conferences that would be required to support a very large infrastructure, but it is possible although maybe not practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the Lync Client SDK.  That this SDK really does is remote control the "Lync Client".  To start the Lync client if it's not running, is just run "lync.exe".  A Lync client install will always have this exe in the path so just running it should work ok. (does for me so far)

Lync 2010 is rather old.  I would use [Lync 2013 Client SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933215.aspx). I use that version as it works for the 2013 client up to the latest Skype For Business 2016 client.

I would download / install the client SDK and check out the examples.  You should to find examples of most things you want (starting a audio conversation, starting a IM conversation, etc).  Pretty much anything you can manually do in the client you can remote control via the Client SDK.

If you want a abstraction layer over the versions, you will have to do that yourself as it's not supported by the SDK's themselves.  Although I wouldn't bother and just support from Lync 2013 and greater.

If your going to do a abstraction layer you will need to test on all the Lync server setups.  Good luck on that...  We have Lync 2103 server and Skype for Business setup here (they can co exist) and it's a huge setup.   A basic setup can be about 6-7 servers and it hooks into your AD.  So to run different versions will require multiple AD's as well. You may need PSTN / sip trunk access to test external calls or federation setup for external network access to/from external clients or federated orgs (like consumer skype).  If you need to go anywhere near high availability you server requirements just skyrocket...

Comment: Thanks Shane. The 2010 decision is a customer constraint, not up to me. If no-one answers in the next couple of days I will mark this as the answer, as I am effectively following your advice so far by going with the client SDK, for now. The app is working, however only on Lync 2010. I wish there was a way to abstract easily over the versions. Conceptually, creating an IM conversation should be "the same" across all the versions. All that changed is the "plumbing" of the "how".